# Close pop-up window after row selecting

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I created a TableView with some data from database table. This view opens in a pop-up window.

When I select any row from the pop-up, my selected value is saved into some global variable.

How can I close the pop-up window after the row is selected? How to redirect to the view from where the pop-up was triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Make this:

1. Create `on_close` event and put its name into `lc_close` var
2. Assign it to your table view click and to popup like this

   ```
   <htmlb:tableView>
   ....
   onRowSelection = "ON_CLOSE" >
   </htmlb:tableView>

   gr_pop_up->set_on_close_event( iv_event_name = lc_close iv_view = me ).
   gr_pop_up->open( ).
   ```
3. Make in popup outbound plug named `EXIT`
4. Fire this plug inside itself recursively

   ```
   method OP_EXIT.
    me->fire_outbound_plug( iv_outbound_plug = 'EXIT' ).
   endmethod.
   ```

This will close your popup.

Answer (score -1):

You can save your value in a data base table or in a Singelton-Object.

What type of pop-up are you using? `POPUP_TO_CONFIRM`? Or a DynPro?

If it's the Function Module `POPUP_TO_CONFIRM` then just implement your logic based on a if statement checking the attribute "`answer`" of the FM.

If it's a DynPro then you need to add logic on the closing event. In a PAI Module.

Comment: Thx for your answer, Stego. It's DynPro type. 
I used this method: 
```
gr_popup = me->comp_controller->window_manager->create_popup( iv_interface_view_name = 'ZUIC/MainWindow'
                                                                    iv_usage_name =  'ZCUName'
                                                                    iv_title = 'Title' ).
```

Comment: What is the class name?

Comment: What do you mean? How could class name help you?

Comment: @user11823122 No, CRM WebUI screens are not DynPro, they are part of a CRM UI framework based on BSPs.